# I have a question about MLP Backpropagation

Tags: c++, deep-learning, backpropagation, mlp

I'm studying MLP reversal while reading this, but there's nothing I'm curious about, so I'm posting questions

In the code above, It used `W`, `V`, `c`, and `b` as parameters for the train function, but I don't understand why we use random and what it means.

Also, I don't know why I `resize` and `make_pair` the value to be handed over to the training function in the training set regarding the vector.

To summarize the questions,

1. What the parameters of `W,V,c,b` mean and why `rand()` is written in the main function
2. Reasons for using `pair`, `resize`, and `make_pair` in Trainset vectors, which are data for training neural networks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

#define Train_Set_Size 20
#define PI 3.141592653589793238463
#define N 5
#define epsilon 0.05
#define epoch 50000

double c[N] = {};
double W[N] = {};
double V[N] = {};
double b = 0;

double sigmoid(double x) {
    return (1.0f / (1.0f + std::exp(-x)));
}

double f_theta(double x) {
    double result = b;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        result += V[i] * sigmoid(c[i] + W[i] * x);
    }
    return result;
}

void train(double x, double y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        W[i] = W[i] - epsilon * 2 * (f_theta(x) - y) * V[i] * x * 
               (1 - sigmoid(c[i] + W[i] * x)) * sigmoid(c[i] + W[i] * x);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        V[i] = V[i] - epsilon * 2 * (f_theta(x) - y) * sigmoid(c[i] + W[i] * x);
    }
    b = b - epsilon * 2 * (f_theta(x) - y);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        c[i] = c[i] - epsilon * 2 * (f_theta(x) - y) * V[i] * 
               (1 - sigmoid(c[i] + W[i] * x)) * sigmoid(c[i] + W[i] * x);
    }
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        W[i] = 2 * rand() / RAND_MAX -1;
        V[i] = 2 * rand() / RAND_MAX -1;
        c[i] = 2 * rand() / RAND_MAX -1;
    }
    vector<pair<double, double>> trainSet;
    trainSet.resize(Train_Set_Size);

    for (int i = 0; i < Train_Set_Size; i++) {
        trainSet[i] = make_pair(i * 2 * PI / Train_Set_Size, sin(i * 2 * PI / Train_Set_Size));
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < epoch; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Train_Set_Size; i++) {
            train(trainSet[i].first, trainSet[i].second);
        }
        std::cout << j << "\r";
    }

    //Plot the results
    vector<float> x;
    vector<float> y1, y2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        x.push_back(i * 2 * PI / 1000);
        y1.push_back(sin(i * 2 * PI / 1000));
        y2.push_back(f_theta(i * 2 * PI / 1000));
    }

    FILE * gp = _popen("gnuplot", "w");
    fprintf(gp, "set terminal wxt size 600,400 \n");
    fprintf(gp, "set grid \n");
    fprintf(gp, "set title '%s' \n", "f(x) = sin (x)");
    fprintf(gp, "set style line 1 lt 3 pt 7 ps 0.1 lc rgb 'green' lw 1 \n");
    fprintf(gp, "set style line 2 lt 3 pt 7 ps 0.1 lc rgb 'red' lw 1 \n");
    fprintf(gp, "plot '-' w p ls 1, '-' w p ls 2 \n");

    //Exact f(x) = sin(x) -> Green Graph
    for (int k = 0; k < x.size(); k++) {
        fprintf(gp, "%f %f \n", x[k], y1[k]);
    }
    fprintf(gp, "e\n");

    //Neural Network Approximate f(x) = sin(x) -> Red Graph
    for (int k = 0; k < x.size(); k++) {
        fprintf(gp, "%f %f \n", x[k], y2[k]);
    }
    fprintf(gp, "e\n");
    
    fflush(gp);


    system("pause");
    _pclose(gp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is just random weight initialization, a basic concept you should be aware to use neural networks.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Oh, thank you. I need to find out about weight initialization